# How to use the loop integers in the list as indices for slicing a string

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indices

I have a list of integers:
`words = [0,4,10,15]`
and a string `s ='heliCopterRotorMotor'`

My task is to apply those integers as indices to the string to slice it.
For example:
`s[words[0:4]]` should be `heli`
`s[words[4:10]]` should be `Copter`
etc.
The code I wrote is not working:

```py
s = 'heliCopterRotorMotor'
words = [0,4,10,15]
spisok = []
for i in words:
   print(s[words[i:i+1]])
```

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

You are slicing the list `words`, not the actual string.

You would want to do something like this instead:

```py
s = 'heliCopterRotorMotor'
words = [0,4,10,15]
for i in range(len(words)-1):
    print(s[words[i]:words[i+1]])
```

Output:

```
heli
Copter
Rotor
```

Comment: Waw! I like this one. I am a new Pythoneer and will definitely look into ZIP thing that I don't know yet. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can get them all with some slicing and trickery:

```
s = 'heliCopterRotorMotor'
words = [0,4,10,15]

for start, end in zip(words, words[1:] + [None]):
   print(s[start:end])

heli
Copter
Rotor
Motor
```

Comment: You're awesome! Thank you very much, I appreciate it. It's really helpful